# webmethod not returning a boolean when code didn't change

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code stopped working today in dev, but on the published version on the server it's still working.
Here's my code :

```
 <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function UserNameExists(ByVal email As String) As Boolean
        Return False
    End Function

<script type="text/javascript">
    function EmailExists() {
        var email = document.getElementById("txtMail").value;
        PageMethods.UserNameExists(email, EmailExistsCallback);
    }

    function EmailExistsCallback(result) {
        if (result == false) {
            emailError.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
        else {
            emailError.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }

    }
</script>  


    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMail" runat="server" MaxLength="300" CssClass="input2" Width="244px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvmail" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtMail" ClientValidationFunction="EmailExists"></asp:CustomValidator>
<span style="visibility: hidden; color: Red; float: right" id="emailError">error.</span>
```

When I add breakpoints in Firefox F12, "result" contains `"\r\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC...rm>\r\n</body>\r\n<html>"` instead of "false". While on the published version it contains false.

Comment: Something obviously changed.  Did you check to make sure your dev web.config matches whats in the published version?

Comment: I tried replacing my web.config witht he one published and still have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have registered the appropriate handler that knows how to process WebMethod requests. This should be in your web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

If you've removed that or caused it to be overwritten, your ASP.NET app won't know how to take the special steps to run a web method.

Comment: In both version I have  <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

Comment: After some testing, the issue is fix when I used the "bin" published folder. So I guess the error is not in the code above.

Comment: When I commented the code I had in my Application_BeginRequest that was doing url rewriting, everything went back to normal. I have no idea how this is related.